# Legendas não aparecem em HTML5 video tag

Tags: html5, html5-video

Olá, estou a criar um sistema de filmes e queria colocar as legendas nos filmes ingleses mas por algum motivo elas não aparecem e quando as vou activar e clico no botão ele desaparece e as legendas não aparecem. Eu tenho um arquivo .vtt com as mesmas:

```
1
00:00:26,460 --> 00:00:30,434
Boa noite, senhoras e senhores.
Estamos prestes a aterrar em Seattle.

2
00:00:30,464 --> 00:00:33,270
Está bom tempo, com vento de leste.

3
00:00:33,300 --> 00:00:36,440
A temperatura no solo é de 20 graus

4
00:00:36,470 --> 00:00:39,347
Em nome da tripulação,
na cabina e no cockpit,
```

Codigo html:

```
<video width="1020" height="640" controls>
      <source src="Rings.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <track label="Português" kind="subtitles" srclang="pt" src="Rings.vtt">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

Alguém sabe qual é o problema?

Comment: Qual navegador vc esta usando ?

Comment: Google Chrome Actualizado

Comment: Eu imagino que elas não são mostradas inicialmente (nem mesmo setando como `default`), o usuário tem de ativa-las. Veja [esse link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video#HTML_Markup) da documentação.

Comment: Mesmo Activando elas não aparecem, não sei porque

Comment: Veja no segundo bloco [dessa parte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video#Building_a_caption_menu), a partir da linha 16. A implementação mostra que vc pode definir o atributo `mode` como `showing` e `data-state` como `active`. Fora isso, se não houver nenhuma msg no console, não sei o que pode acontecer.

Comment: @IMM Acredito que você já tenha conseguido resolver o problema, se não, dê uma olhada na minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Existem alguns pontos a serem corrigidos no seu arquivode legendas... O separador decimal para os millesegundos deve ser o `.` e não a `,`. É recomendado que você inicie a primeira linha do seu `.vtt` com a assinatura `WEBVTT`. Seus arquivos podem ser validados nesse [site](https://quuz.org/webvtt/).

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:26.460 --> 00:00:30.434
Boa noite, senhoras e senhores.
Estamos prestes a aterrar em Seattle.

2
00:00:30.464 --> 00:00:33.270
Está bom tempo, com vento de leste.

3
00:00:33.300 --> 00:00:36.440
A temperatura no solo é de 20 graus.

4
00:00:36.470 --> 00:00:39.347
Em nome da tripulação,
na cabina e no cockpit,
```

**Outros pontos importantes:**

1. Tanto o vídeo quando os subtitles precisam ser disponibilizados através de um serviço `http`, não funciona localmente simplesmente abrindo o .html no browser.
2. Caso os arquivos não estejam disponíveis no mesmo domínio do seu site, é necessário adicionar o atributo `crossorigin` no seu elemento `<video>`.
3. Se você declarar a propriedade `default` em sua `<track>` o player já irá exibir aquela legenda por padrão na reprodução do conteúdo.

Veja uma demo funcionando logo abaixo, coloquei duas legendas iguais em tracks diferentes porque ainda não encontrei um exemplo melhor.

```html
<video width="50%" src="//thepaciellogroup.github.io/AT-browser-tests/video/ElephantsDream.mp4" controls crossorigin="anonymous">
  <track kind="subtitles" src="//thepaciellogroup.github.io/AT-browser-tests/video/subtitles-en.vtt" srclang="en" label="Inglês" default>
  <track kind="subtitles" src="//thepaciellogroup.github.io/AT-browser-tests/video/subtitles-en.vtt" srclang="pt" label="Português">     
</video>
```

Comment: Leandro Angelo, as duas legendas estão em inglês, elas estão apontando para o mesmo endereço.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Sim, eu sei, era apenas para demonstrar que ambas declarações funcionam com o carregamento do arquivo. Afinal, o player não sabe o que está exibindo, apenas relaciona as marcações com o andamento da execução do vídeo....